# Run script when an always-connected drive is mounted

Tags: mount, sd-card, udev

How can I trigger a script to be run when an **always connected** drive is mounted?

I have tried `udev`, specifically placing a rule `99-local.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
KERNEL=="mmcblk0",ACTION=="mount",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

And reloading the rules. But the script does not run when the drive is mounted.

Note that the drive is an **SD card**, hence the `mmcblk0` block device name. It is **not** a USB drive and is **not** being hotplugged.

Comment: The script does not run, probably because the udev rule is overlooked. It is probably overlooked because in principle yr sd card is mounted automatically under  `/media/yr-username/yr-mmcbki0-tag` Confirm or correct me if I am wrong by checking whether yr sd card is mounted or not under `/media./...`. Run `mount -l | grep mmcblk0` and post result.  Depending on yr response I may have a working solution tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But there do seem to be deeper issues with using `udev` in this particular case. Detail in answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw yr comment now because I was not notified (i.e. you failed to include @Cbhihe in yr comment to my comment). Glad however you could get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that this is not easy to accomplish with `udev`. With `udevadm monitor -p` I verified that, when mounted, my SD card fires no `ACTION=="mount"` event in `udev`. I read somewhere that the `mount` event has been deprecated or removed, which if true would explain it. `udev`, after all, is supposed to manage hotplugging.

In addition, `udev`-triggered scripts must complete very quickly because they block `udev` while running. Not ideal for a substantial task, for example backup.

I achieved my aim by writing a `systemd` service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` using `ExecStart` for `.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script to run when drive mounted at /path/to/Stuff
Requires=path-to-Stuff.mount
After=path-to-Stuff.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=path-to-Stuff.mount
```

Works correctly, though it does require specifying the mount point.

Comment: Could you post your complete service file in you answer? I want to learn from the way you did it.

Comment: @Sneetsher Done.

Comment: You're my hero - upvoted